# Are their any benefit we got if we use Window Server instead of Window 7 for web development?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

last time in a blog post i read that someone show me the benefit for using Visual studio on window server instead of window 7..

are their any benefit we got by using server edition of window instead of OS.can someone explain what this mean.

Answer (score 0):

i think he is talking about the integrated IIS and other stuff in windows server but nothing you can't get by simple googling and downloading